# React router nested routes. Not rendering child routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have a parent component called Dashboard that's being rendered as a Route like so:

```
const Routes = ({ authenticated }: { authenticated: boolean }) => (

    <Switch>
        <AuthenticatedRoute path="/home" exact={true} component={Dashboard} authenticated={authenticated} />
        <UnauthenticatedRoute path="/login" exact={true} component={Login} authenticated={authenticated} />
        <AuthenticatedRoute path="/onboarding" exact={true} component={Onboarding} authenticated={authenticated} />
        <AuthenticatedRoute path="/meets" exact={true} component={Meets} authenticated={authenticated} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>

)

export default Routes
```

Within the Dashboard component I'd like to also render routes, the component looks like this:

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component<IProps, {}> {
    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navigation />

                <Route exact={true} path="/home" component={Home} />
                <Route exact={true} path="/home/profile" component={Profile} />
                <Route exact={true} path="/home/messages" component={Messages} />

                HALLO
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I've also tried wrapping those Routes inside a Switch, same problem.

For the sake of me I can't figure out why this isn't working. The Home route renders fine but Profile or Message doesn't. When I try hit those URL's I get back the NotFound route component found in the 1st code block.

The path has been set as '/home/profile/ and '/home/messages' so why aren't they being rendered when I'm hitting those URL's?

I've tried mocking everybody's solution at nested routes and I can't seem to solve my issue.

Comment: Make sure  Switch is having Route or Redirect as direct children.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because you are using `exact` prop in your top route configuration. Drop it:

```
<AuthenticatedRoute path="/home" component={Dashboard} authenticated={authenticated} />
```

Also, `exact` is enough, you don't have to use it like `exact={true}`.

Comment: Lifesaver, thank you! I added exact={true} because I'm using TypeScript.

Comment: You are welcome. Oh, sorry. I don't know TypeScript, then go ahead :)